# Inverse Gamma in Python

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to plot the pdf of an inverse gamma distribution in Python. I have different location and scale parameters and I want to make the pdf for all values to visualise how the different values for the parameters affect the distribution. I found an example online but I don't really understand how it works. Let say I have an inverse gamma distribution with location=4 and scale=5. Could someone suggest how I would plot the pdf of this distribution?

Answer (score 0):

See the example included in the SciPy documentation for `scipy.stats.invgamma`:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.invgamma.html#scipy.stats.invgamma